# Use of quotations when introducing a character alias

Tags: punctuation

Should the following aliases be enclosed in quotations? I believe it may be down to personal preference and I prefer this format, but keen to opinions.

His name is Dave, "The Dude", and he's a sucker for punishment.

Meet Chev, "The Squirrel Hunter", the most loyal guard dog around.

VS

His name is Dave, The Dude, and he's a sucker for punishment.

Meet Chev, The Squirrel Hunter, the most loyal guard dog around.

Comment: Don't capitalize 'The' in 'the Dude' or 'the Squirrel Hunter'. I'd use the 2nd version (without quotes) unless it is specifically referring to a quote: Sharon calls him "the Dude", but we just call him Dad.

Comment: You should capitalize "The" here as it is the first word in the title. Elvis "The King", Ali "The Greatest", Jeff "The Dude" Leboswki. We should lowercase articles, conjunctions, and prepositions - unless it's the first word: Frank "The Chairman of the Board" Sinatra. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If using quotation marks, the comma needs to appear before the final quotation mark.

Comment: @JasonBassford could you share some refs, this is not the same as quoting dialog. thanks

Comment: @SamuelG It makes no difference. It has nothing to do with dialogue. The use of a period or a comma next to a final quotation mark follows the same punctuation rules, dialogue or not. Look at any style guide.

Comment: @JasonBassford [This style guide disagrees](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf).  In *American*, perhaps this may be the case, but not in *English*.  Considering the vast opportunities for confusion and misinterpretation to which it can lead (*He told me that the password was "Sw0rd-f!sh."*), I feel it is the inferior option in either case.

Comment: @Chronocidal Which is exactly why almost all style guides, not least of all *The Chicago Manual of Style* say to use italics for *Sw0rd-f!sh* rather than quotation marks at all, or to use British punctuation in such exceptions and contexts ('Sw0rd-f!sh'.) even though you normally wouldn't. And don't confuse UK style guides with US style guide. If you're going to use the UK style, use single quotations marks.

Answer (score 2):

The former (the one with quotations) is probably the better one. Not only does it look better, but you are saying a nickname for each character. The only way I have seen it is with quotation marks. But you can do whatever. Just keep in mind that the quotation marks will probably work better.